# How can I make a civi event registration form that collects the individual's information as well as the organization to which they are affiliated?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

How can I make a Civi event registration form that collects the individual's information as well as the organization to which they are affiliated? Would I have to use a webform? We're on 4.6.8, Drupal.

Comment: Joe, how did you handle this? We've got nearly the same requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of webforms where the user is logged in and we have set the auto-complete to be based on the relationship between the user and their organisation.

Contact 1 is the individual and Contact 2 is the organisation.

I would imagine that using non-logged in users is similar, depending on how exposed the organisation list is? Would it make two contacts if there were none matching then create a relationship?

Comment: Darren, we would ask Participants in the Event to select an organization from a dropdown - for some existing contacts/Participants a Relationship to an existing Organization may already exist in Civi, others might be both new contacts/Participants and new Organizations to be added to Civi and the relationship created (Participant is a Member (or Board Member, or Staff) of the Organization).